# Extracting skills from a job description using TF-IDF or Word2Vec

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, word2vec, pos-tagger, tfidfvectorizer

I have a situation where I need to extract the skills of a particular applicant who is applying for a job from the job description avaialble and store it as a new column altogether.
The dataframe X looks like following:

```
Job_ID        Job_Desc 
1             Applicant should posses technical capabilities including proficient knowledge of python and SQL
2             Applicant should posses technical capabilities including proficient knowledge of python and SQL and R
```

The resultant output should look like following:

```
Job_ID       Skills
1            Python,SQL
2            Python,SQL,R
```

I have used tf-idf count vectorizer to get the most important words within the Job_Desc column but still I am not able to get the desired skills data in the output. Could this be achieved somehow with Word2Vec using skip gram or CBOW model?

My code looks like this :

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv=CountVectorizer(max_df=0.50)
word_count_vector=cv.fit_transform(X)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
tfidf_transformer=TfidfTransformer(smooth_idf=True,use_idf=True)
tfidf_transformer.fit(word_count_vector)

def sort_coo(coo_matrix):
tuples = zip(coo_matrix.col, coo_matrix.data)
return sorted(tuples, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]), reverse=True)

def extract_topn_from_vector(feature_names, sorted_items, topn=10):
"""get the feature names and tf-idf score of top n items"""

#use only topn items from vector
sorted_items = sorted_items[:topn]

score_vals = []
feature_vals = []

for idx, score in sorted_items:
    fname = feature_names[idx]

    #keep track of feature name and its corresponding score
    score_vals.append(round(score, 3))
    feature_vals.append(feature_names[idx])

#create a tuples of feature,score
#results = zip(feature_vals,score_vals)
results= {}
for idx in range(len(feature_vals)):
    results[feature_vals[idx]]=score_vals[idx]

return results

feature_names=cv.get_feature_names()
doc=X[0]

tf_idf_vector=tfidf_transformer.transform(cv.transform([doc]))
sorted_items=sort_coo(tf_idf_vector.tocoo())
keywords=extract_topn_from_vector(feature_names,sorted_items,10)
print("\n=====Title=====")
print(X[0])
print("\n===Keywords===")
for k in keywords:
   print(k,keywords[k])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of a way that TF-IDF, Word2Vec, or other simple/unsupervised algorithms could, alone, identify the kinds of 'skills' you need.

You'll likely need a large hand-curated list of skills – at the very least, as a way to automate the evaluation of methods that purport to extract skills.

With a curated list, then something like Word2Vec might help suggest synonyms, alternate-forms, or related-skills. (For known skill X, and a large Word2Vec model on your text, terms similar-to X are likely to be similar skills – but not guaranteed, so you'd likely still need human review/curation.)

With a large-enough dataset mapping texts to *outcomes* – like, a candidate-description text (resume) mapped-to whether a human reviewer chose them for an interview, or hired them, or they succeeded in a job, you might be able to identify terms that are highly predictive of fit in a certain job role. Those terms might often be de facto 'skills'. But discovering those correlations could be a much larger learning project.

Comment: you can try using Name Entity Recognition as well!

Answer (score 0):

Here's [a paper](https://confusedcoders.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Job-Skills-extraction-with-LSTM-and-Word-Embeddings-Nikita-Sharma.pdf) which suggests an approach similar to the one you suggested.

It advises using a combination of LSTM + word embeddings (whether they be from word2vec, BERT, etc.)
You likely won't get great results with TF-IDF due to the way it calculates importance. The skills are likely to only be mentioned once, and the postings are quite short so many other words used are likely to only be mentioned once also.

As the paper suggests, you will probably need to create a training dataset of text from job postings which is labelled either skill or not skill.